# how to save a primary key value from a table to another table?

Tags: c#

I want to save **PersonId** value from Person table to password table but i'm having a problem. My problem is that it saves zero on **PersonId** on password table instead of saving the value(personId) that is auto generated in person table. help will be appreciated.

**View model**

```
public class UserVM
  {
     public int PersonID { get; set; }        
     public string FirstName { get; set; }       
     public string LastName { get; set; }      
     public string UserName { get; set; }       
     public string Password1 { get; set; }     
 }
```

**password**

```
  public partial class Password
{       
public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }       
public string Password1 { get; set; }
public int PersonID { get; set; }
 }
```

**person**

```
   public partial class Person1
  {

public int PersonID { get; set;     
public string Title { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }       
public string LastName { get; set; }      
public string UserName { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> UserAuthRoleId { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Password> Passwords { get; set; }
 }
```

**Controller**

```
  // POST: api/Person1
[ResponseType(typeof(Person1))]
public IHttpActionResult PostPerson1(UserVM vm)
{
    var pers = new Person1
    {
        Title = vm.Title,
        FirstName = vm.FirstName,
        LastName = vm.LastName,
        UserName = vm.UserName,               
    };
    var word = new Password();
    using (var context = new VybeEstoreEntities1())
    {
       context.People1.Add(pers);
        word.PersonID = pers.PersonID;                            
        word.Password1 = vm.Password1;               
        context.Passwords.Add(word);
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
```

**Screenshots**

Person table

[image]

Password table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using EntityFramework Code First you'll want to declare the relationship between Person1 and Password. For example:

```
public partial class Person1
{
    public int PersonID { get; set;     
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }       
    public string LastName { get; set; }      
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserAuthRoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Password Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then omit the line where you manually set word.PersonId and you omit the PersonId field in Password.

Comment: When u saying i must omit the line word.PersonId what will tell the code to save on the personid on password table?

Comment: and yes i do ve this on my model : public virtual ICollection<Password> Passwords { get; set; }

Comment: EntityFramework will do it for you because it knows there is a relationship between the two entities. You cannot set it manually because before you actually save the Person1 entity it doesn't have an ID yet.